# Complexity of reversing a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, big-o

If I was to reverse a string using:

```
"hello there!"[::-1]
```

Would it be `O(n)`, because the algorithm has to reverse more characters if the input string is larger?

Comment: `n` is the size of the string. So yes.

Comment: That's just a copy. `[::-1]` copies all elements into a new string with step -1, so yes, O(n).

Comment: Thank you both :)

Comment: It's not O(n) because it has to do that but because it doesn't have to do more than that.

Comment: @StefanPochmann because it won't have to do anything more than once per character in its worst-case scenario?

Comment: Yeah... I just meant that your "because" sounds like reasoning for why it's not better than O(n), not for why it's O(n).

Comment: O(n) means that if the string length (n) grows, the time requested to perform the function stays proportional to the string length (it's a linear function of n) and doesn't worsen